# ¿Como saber si se esta ejecutando correctamente la consulta?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access-2013

Tengan buen día, hoy vengo con un problema que no he podido solucionar. Estoy trabajando con C# .Net y una base en Microsoft Access, estoy queriendo hacer un Update a una tabla.

El problema radica en que no sé si estoy ejecutando correctamente el uso de parametros, ademas de eso no se si realmente se esta ejecutando la consulta.

Tengo un MesssageBox para desplegar que el dato fue actualizado, dicho MessageBox se muestra pero no actualiza el valor en la tabla.

Aqui el codigo de el boton "Guardar":

```
  try
        {

            conexion.Open();
            string update = "UPDATE usuarios set nombre = @nombre, tipo_usuario = @tipo_usuario, iniciales = @iniciales, identidad = @identidad, direccion = @direccion, telefono = @telefono, celular = @celular, correo = @correo WHERE codigo=@codigo";
            OleDbCommand comando7 = new OleDbCommand(update, conexion);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", txtId.Text);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtNombre.Text);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_usuario", txtTipo.Text);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iniciales", txtInciales.Text);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identidad", txtIdentidad.Text);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", txtCelular.Text);
            comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", txtCorreo.Text);
            comando7.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario actualizado con exito", "Exito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
```

Entonces quisiera saber si es de esa manera o si tengo cambiar algo para actualizar el valor ya que no esta actualizando. Si ocupan alguna otra info estare pendiente.Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas Luis,

Según pone en la [`página de OleDbCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) el proveedor de OleDb no admite parámetros con nombre, en su caso se debe usar `'?'` y los parámetros deben ser añadidos a la colección de parámetros exactamente en el mismo orden que se tiene en la `query`.

Sabiendo esto, tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
    try
    {
        conexion.Open();
        string update = "UPDATE usuarios set nombre = ?, tipo_usuario = ?, iniciales = ?, identidad = ?, direccion = ?, telefono = ?, celular = ?, correo = ? WHERE codigo = ?";
        OleDbCommand comando7 = new OleDbCommand(update, conexion);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtNombre.Text);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_usuario", txtTipo.Text);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iniciales", txtInciales.Text);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identidad", txtIdentidad.Text);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", txtCelular.Text);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", txtCorreo.Text);
        comando7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", txtId.Text);
        comando7.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Usuario actualizado con exito", "Exito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conexion.Close();
    }
```

Para comprobar si la `query` se ha ejecutado correctamente y hacer el display del `MessageBox`, te recomiendo usar siempre el valor que devuelve el `ExecuteNonQuery` para comprobar las líneas afectadas, de la siguiente forma:

```
if (comando7.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Usuario actualizado con exito", "Exito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias.